ScrollIntoView does not take into account a right panel width
I have this TS code:
 public openPanel(widget: Widget): void {
    const doesWidgetHaveFields = this.widgetFormService.doesWidgetHaveFields(widget.widgetType);

    this.store.dispatch([
      doesWidgetHaveFields
        ? new SetRightPanelState(RightPanelState.Edit)
        : new SetRightPanelState(RightPanelState.Hidden)
   ]);

      const selectedWidget = this.options?.api?.getItemComponent?.(widget);

      setTimeout(() => {
        selectedWidget?.el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' });
      
      }, 2500);
    
  }

In the dispatch i set the right panel to be visible.
The right panel width is 500px
On the setTimeout the scrollIntoView doesn't take in to a account the right panel width.
how can i fix this?
